# Send email with signature images outlook 2016 VBA

Tags: html, vba, email, outlook

I have followed a tutorial to send automated emails using reminder and calendar appointments.
The "base" is from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1567-outlook-send-schedule-recurring-email.html
The problem with this is the images in signature become html tags.
Ron de Bruin's code here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm can add the signature in html and it almost worked.

I get text, font, colors and links correct but the images are empty boxes with red x.
I looked at the source of the message and it seems the code for signature grabs hardcoded relative img sources.
So i tried to add the "replace" code to edit the sources in message to absolute path.
And it worked! But only on my computer. 
The images are not added, they are just linked to.

Anyone who has a solution how to **add** (or attach) the images so that the signature looks correct?

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal item As Object)
    Dim MItem As MailItem
    Set MItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    If item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If item.Categories <> "Beställa material mail" Then ' make sure it's correct category
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Now > item.End + 6 / 24 Then ' if the appointment time was when computer was off (or long delay) don't email.
        MsgBox item.Subject & " är inte skickat för att det är för sent." ' "subject" is not send because it's too late.
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Below is from https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\Axfood.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    'replace incorrect img sources.
    Signature = Replace(Signature, "src=" & Chr(34) & "Axfood-filer/image", "src=" & Chr(34) & Environ("appdata") & "/Microsoft/Signatures/Axfood-filer/image")

    ' send email
    MItem.To = item.Location
    MItem.Subject = item.Subject
    MItem.HTMLBody = item.Body & Signature
    MItem.Send
    Set MItem = Nothing
End Sub


Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
'Dick Kusleika
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

EDIT;

Example img source in the Outlook signature file:
`<img border=0 width=21 height=21
src="Axfood-filer/image010.jpg" v:shapes="_x0000_i1030">`

This is edited with the replace function in the code to a absolute path on harddrive.

Signature files can be foung at: `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures`

Comment: Show the actual HTML. It MUST have `<img src="http(s)://pathtoserver.com/pathtoimage/image.jpg" />` Also proper HTML mime headers are needed

Comment: Thats the thing. It's not "http", Outlook saves the images locally and the HTML has a local adress. This is one of the images from the HTML: `<img border=0 width=21 height=21
src="Axfood-filer/image010.jpg" v:shapes="_x0000_i1030">`

Comment: And if you add `<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />` to the text?

Comment: If I do that I get this in the source: `<img border=0 width=21 height=21
src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150010.jpg" v:shapes="_x0000_i1030">`but the image does not show up. Not on the computer or on my Android phone.

Comment: Sorry... I see my misstake. the `10` is still there in the link. Give me a minute and I will try again.

Comment: @mplungjan On Android it is correct. I get the 300x150 grey image. I think Outlook does not show it due to it's not correct html to have a src without the ".jpg"

Comment: So use https://blog.jmwhite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Outlook-2013.jpg

Comment: @mplungjan Again it works on Android (and on iPhone too) but Outlook 2016 does not download the image. This can be due to company restrictions. But either way that does not help, or am I misunderstanding something? I can't add http links to the images in the email since they are not on internet.

Comment: Then you can try data-uris

Comment: What is data-uris? You mean base64 images? Can VBA do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer that works on Outlook 2016, and gives an "OK" result on Android/iPhone.

I attach the images through vba and inline them with html code.

```
Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment
Dim colAttach As Outlook.Attachments

Set colAttach = MItem.Attachments

' attach the images to the email
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add(Environ("appdata") & "/Microsoft/Signatures/Axfood-filer/image001.png")
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add(Environ("appdata") & "/Microsoft/Signatures/Axfood-filer/image003.jpg")
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add(Environ("appdata") & "/Microsoft/Signatures/Axfood-filer/image005.jpg")
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add(Environ("appdata") & "/Microsoft/Signatures/Axfood-filer/image007.jpg")
Set oAttach = colAttach.Add(Environ("appdata") & "/Microsoft/Signatures/Axfood-filer/image009.jpg")

'add the images to signature string with html formatting.
Signature = Signature & "<a href='http://www.axfood.se'><IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:image001.png' align=baseline width=151 border=0></a><br><br>"
Signature = Signature & "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/axfoodkoncernen/'><IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:image003.jpg' align=baseline border=0></a> "
Signature = Signature & "<a href='https://twitter.com/axfood'><IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:image005.jpg' align=baseline border=0></a> "
Signature = Signature & "<a href='https://www.linkedin.com/company/axfood'><IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:image007.jpg' align=baseline border=0></a> "
Signature = Signature & "<a href='https://www.instagram.com/axfoodkoncernen/'><IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='cid:image009.jpg' align=baseline border=0></a> "
```

The result is a correct email for Outlook.
On Android the images are attached but not inlined in email.
On iPhone the images are inlined in email but links are not spanning the images.

iPhone example:
link link link link
image image image image

instead of image beeing the actual link.